# Formatting dates in ASP.Net data binding expressions

Tags: asp.net, itemtemplate

Can you format a date when using a data binding expression in ASP.NET?

DataFormatString works for a BoundField in a GridView, but not in a ItemTemplate label using a data binding expression.  Ideally I'd like to use a custom format string like {0:dd-MMM-yyyy} to format the date.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIELD_NAME")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblLabel" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("FIELD_NAME", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```